# Getting started with Rails and Ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, actionmailer

I'm building an app which has a "paging" interface which has a simple text area box, a select to determine who I should be "paging" (sending a message to) and a submit button.

I'd like to build this with Ajax functionality so that when I submit the page a small div shows the message and the result (successful, failed, etc).

My controller is simple in that it will have an index, new, create action.  The create action should post the message on the page as well as trigger actionmailer to send out the page based on the individual selected in the form select.

I guess the problem I'm having is with the view code and the jquery.  Trying to understand how that works has me a bit confused since I'm new.

Can someone provide me with an example of a one-page post interface that can do something like this?  So far it looks like my code is right, but I'm missing the jquery stuff and the rest of the magic.

Here's what I have so far:

```
paging_controller
class PagingController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @pages = Paging.all
  end


  def new
     @page = Paging.new
  end

  def show
    @page = Paging.find(params[:id])

    respond_with @page
  end

  def create
      @page = Paging.new(params[:page])

        if @page.valid?
          PagingMailer.new_message(@page).deliver
          redirect_to calls_path, notice: "Call was successfully created."
        else
          flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
          render :new
        end
      end

end

index.html.erb
<h2>Paging Interface</h2>


    <div class="form">
    <%= render 'form' %>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
    <%= render 'page'%>
    </div>

_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@page, :remote => true) do |f| %>

  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :message %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

_page.html.erb

<%= content_tag_for(:li, page) do %>
  <p><%= page.body %></p>
  <span class="age">Posted at <%= time_ago_in_words(page.created_at) %> ago.
 </span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Some screencasts with Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=ajax)

[Railstutorial: A working follow button with Ajax](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec%3aa_working_follow_button_with_ajax)

Comment: I've read through these but a lot of RB's videos are outdated with the new pipeline stuff.  I'm really just looking to wire up the js portion, that's what's missing right now.